# Backing up Wordpress before an update, what's the easiest way to do this?

Tags: backup

I'm about to update my Wordpress blog to the latest version. It was recommended that I backup my posts and database first. It seems like a plugin would be the easiest way for me to do this. What's the best plugin available for this? Searching Wordpress' site I found the BackUpWordPress plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/backupwordpress/

Alternatively, if a plugin isn't recommended, how should I do this instead?

Comment: _SIDENOTE_ Back-Up is never the problem. Getting your site up and running is :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Backups) covers this topic VERY thoroughly. Personally, I use [WP-DB-Backup](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-db-backup/), it's the most popular backup plugin that I know of, and it's really easy to use.

Comment: -1 as it only backup the DB and not the files, therefor you can not just reinstall whatever the backup is and you need an additional process to backup the files

Comment: @MarkKaplun I no longer dev for WordPress in any serious capacity, so some of this information may be dated. That said, I believe when you update WordPress, it recommends that you backup your database, not your files. Further, the question specifically says "It was recommended that I backup my posts and database first....What's the best plugin available for this?", so it seems that I answered the question. If you are looking for how to backup files and database, perhaps a new question is best.

Comment: As kaiser said in the comment, and this applies to all software not just wordpress, if you have only the DB file how can you rstore the site from it? You need the code and the images. You should not assume that just because someone wrote in the codex 10 years ago that DB backup is enough, that the upgrade process can not have some terminal failure that will leave you without any files.There is only one way to do proper backup, and you just lie to yourself about having a backup if you don't do it properly

Comment: I agree that a database backup is insufficient for a restore, but that was not the question asked. I'm no longer familiar with the WP update mechanisms, but I don't any non-core files would be modified, especially in /wp-content/uploads/. WP update does make one-way database schema changes, so a update rollback is required, a database backup would be all that would be required as all unique files would have been untouched. Thus, in my opinion, the question is framed correctly in asking how to do a DB backup for a WP update.

Comment: There are plugins that do it properly like the duplicator, so why use an inferior one?

Comment: This answer was written in 2012, As best I can tell, the duplicator came into existence in April or 2014. If this answer is out of date, feel free to update it or submit your own. It does no change the fact that this answer correctly answers the question that was asked, which you have completely failed to address. Since you haven't presented a cogent argument as to why this answer is wrong, I will not be returning to this comment thread, hopefully this discussion is sufficient for future readers.

Comment: You are obviously right, and I have no idea why I even read it, but well, it doesn't keep up with the times and people that read it can see why. I personally would have downvoted it in 2012 as well.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to what kaiser said above. Any of the popular/top-rated backup plugins in the WP plugin repository will do the job of backing up for you. this one is one of the most popular ones... https://wordpress.org/plugins/updraftplus/ The hard part is restoring your back up files. Hopefully/realistically, restoring shouldn't need to happen often. For the relatively small number of times you need to restore, I think it's worth paying someone to do that work. It has never cost me more than $50.

Tips:

-- Be aware, a database backup doesn't backup up your images! So keep a local copy of all your images.

-- DON'T rely on your host/anyone else to make backups for you, unless you pay them and you have a large website, then you can look at a dedicated service like VaultPress.

--If possible make your own backups and store them on a) your computer, b). a usb and c). online such as dropbox.

-- Delete any unused plugins, themes and images as they add a lot of space to your backup.